# 3D print Ember Autodesk issues affect print quality

Tags: print-quality, dlp

does anyone know something about Autodesk Ember print issues? 
Currently I am working on my master thesis and I would like to print with the Ember 3D printer a holder (see attachment) using the Luxaprint 3D mould from Detax.

[image: This is the holder I would like to print with a size of 9 mm x 9 mm[1]]
[image]

My problem is as you can see it, the resolution 
of print quality is very bad. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi Lisia, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! It is a bit difficult to see with this low resolution image. Do you have some better pictures?

Comment: Hi Oskar, Thank you! I add another picture maybe you can see the bad resolution of the print now better

Comment: To be honest, not really... but in my defense, I'm nearsighted and colorblind.

Comment: Okay, let me take new pictures and then I will upload it - sorry for that!

Comment: what are the dimensions of the item? How long did you set the cure times?

Comment: The dimensions are 9 mm x 9 mm and the cure time is 4 seconds for all layers